# pandas: sort alphabetically if rows have same rank

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe with two rows that have the same value:

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['alpha','beta','theta','delta','epsilon'],'b':[1,2,3,3,4]})

         a  b
0    alpha  1
1     beta  2
2    theta  3
3    delta  3
4  epsilon  4
```

Now I want to sort them based on column B:

```
testdf['rank'] = testdf['b'].rank(ascending=False)

         a  b  rank
0    alpha  1   5.0
1     beta  2   4.0
2    theta  3   2.5
3    delta  3   2.5
4  epsilon  4   1.0
```

Since rows 2 and 3 have the same rank, I'd like to arrange them in alphabetical order for the viewer:

```
         a  b  rank
0    alpha  1   5.0
1     beta  2   4.0
3    delta  3   2.5
2    theta  3   2.5
4  epsilon  4   1.0
```

But I'm not sure how to do this. Maybe I could group them by rank and order them...? I'm not sure how to do that in-place, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to sort by more than one column using [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), what you want is to sort by `rank` first, then by the `a` column, and if you want it to happen inplace, we use `inplace=True` like below:

```
In [14]: testdf.sort_values(['rank', 'a'], ascending=[False, True], inplace=True)

In [15]: testdf
Out[15]: 
         a  b  rank
0    alpha  1   5.0
1     beta  2   4.0
3    delta  3   2.5
2    theta  3   2.5
4  epsilon  4   1.0
```

Which is the result you want and inplace, if you don't use `inplace=True` the resulting dataframe will be returned from the operation.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the functionality to sort by more than one value at once! I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me :)